# Unable to display the list with the custom view

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have to create a FAQ page for my sharepont 2010 site. I have created a custom list and a corrosponding view named FAQView. When adding the list on the page, it is being displayed in "current view". Even after editing the webpart and selecting the view as FAQView still the display does not change.

Thanks in Advance,
Ankita

Comment: what webpart are you using?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? There is not a real question here. Maybe some additional information on how the List and View are created will also help in solving your problem.

Comment: list view webpart too display the custom list.

Comment: have you tried any other default views?

Comment: Yes I have. I have even modified AllItems in sharepoint designer and added it still there isnt any change.Do i need to publish the view from designer somehow?